# Bootstrap invalid input on chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a required field on one of my forms, however on chrome it is way below where it should be. Anyone know how I can manage this? [image]

Comment: An image isn't very helpful. Post your code.

Comment: there isn't much besides "required" when we have our server back up I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These popup for required field are managed by the browser, i don't think that you can act on.

You can try to send a feedback to google:

chrome://feedback/